# Defer HTML, CSS, & Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to defer the html, css, and js functions for Google Plus, Facebook, and Twitter.

Without deferring the html I can get everything to work. As soon as I add the deferring of the html everything works (deferred html and css) except the Google Plus and Twitter buttons...neither appear, but the Facebook button does. Trying to avoid using jquery.

index.html without deferring the html and css

css

```
#soc {
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:.6;
    margin-left:-40px
}
#soc li {
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:100%;
    padding:3px
}
```

html

```
<div id="ac">
<ul id="soc">
    <li><div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div></li>
    <li><div class="fb-like" data-href="http:/example.com" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-hashtags="test">Tweet</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>function downloadJSAtOnload(){
var element=document.createElement("script");
element.src="speed.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if(window.addEventListener)window.addEventListener("load",downloadJSAtOnload,false);
else 
if(window.attachEvent)window.attachEvent("onload",downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload=downloadJSAtOnload</script>
```

in speed.js

```
(function () {
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();

(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

! function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
    if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }
}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
```

Working Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hWXNH/

index.html - removed all the html from div id ac and move it to an external html page called speed.html and removed all the css and moved it to an external css page called social.css

```
<div id="ac"></div>

<script>function downloadJSAtOnload(){
var element=document.createElement("script");
element.src="speed.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if(window.addEventListener)window.addEventListener("load",downloadJSAtOnload,false);
else 
if(window.attachEvent)window.attachEvent("onload",downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload=downloadJSAtOnload</script>
```

in speed.js

```
var xObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
xObj.open('GET', 'speed.html', true);
xObj.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("ac").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xObj.send();

var stylesheet = document.createElement("link");
stylesheet.href = "social.css";
stylesheet.rel = "stylesheet";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(stylesheet);
window.___gcfg = {
    parsetags: 'onload'
};

(function () {
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();

(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

! function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
    if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }
}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
```

What is breaking just the Google Plus One and Twitter Buttons but not the Facebook button when I defer the html?

Comment: +1 `Trying to avoid using jquery.`

Comment: Mee too :) +1 for trying to avoid using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to defer the html, css, and js functions for Google Plus, Facebook, and Twitter.

What for? The scripts are all loaded asynchronously anyway; and “deferring” that small piece of HTML code, that *on itself does nothing* – what benefit are you supposing to gain from that?

Anyway, AFAIK all of those scripts are per default set to parse to document for elements to replace once they are finished loading – so if your “deferred” HTML code hasn’t made it into the DOM by then already, they find nothing to work on and do nothing further.

So you’d either have to instruct them all to not parse when they are loaded, but do that at some point later (for Facebook that’d mean removing `#xfbml=1` from the script address, and calling `FB.XFBML.parse` later; for the other’s I don’t know of the top of my head); or not embedded them directly, but only *after* you AJAX call & HTML insert has finished (by placing those self-executing functions inside your callback).

But as I said, I doubt that “deferring” that small piece of HTML code will result in any measurable benefit at all; looks like it is just giving you more *trouble*.

Comment: trying to walk before I run. My intentions further down the road would be to defer more than just that small piece of html. In addition the Facebook button already works as is regardless of being deferred or not being deferred.  It is the Google Plus One and Twitter that does not show when deferred. A note to mention...in the deferred state the "Tweet" from the anchor tag does appear.